# If $W = \{(aaab)∣a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ How would I find a dimension for $W$?

Tags: linear-algebra

Consider $W$ the subset of the vector space $V$ where $V$ is all 2x2 matrices: if $W = \{(aaab)∣a,b\in \mathbb{R}\}$ how would I find a dimension for $W$?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like it's $2$-dimensional.  $\{(1110),(0001)\}$, to use your notation, would be a basis.

Comment: thank you :) i understood

Comment: but what if i have (a -a b c)

Comment: That would be $3$ dimensional.